# fgetws fails to get the exact wide char string from FILE*

Tags: c++, file-io, wstring, widechar

I am using fgetws to get some string line by line from a FILE. The FILE I have is from a popen command. Here is the code snippet:

```
    FILE* pInstalledApps = popen( command.c_str(), "r" );
    if( NULL != pInstalledApps )
    {
        wchar_t currentAppPath [kMaximumAppPathLength];

        // Reading app paths one line at a time.
        while ( ! feof (pInstalledApps) )
        {
            if ( fgetws  ( currentAppPath, kMaximumAppPathLength, pInstalledApps) == NULL )
            {
                break;
            }
            wchar_t *pCharPos = NULL;
            if ( ( pCharPos = wcschr( currentAppPath, L'\n' ) ) != NULL )
            {
                *pCharPos = L'\0';
            }
            std::wstring appPath( currentAppPath );

                            //Do something with the wstring
        }
        pclose( pInstalledApps );
    }
```

When the string currentAppPath that i gets has wide char strings, the appPath that I get doesnot have the expected string. For example if the string that I get from the FILE is `10teciêênks` my appPath variable will be having `10tecieÌeÌnks`.

Comment: Locale / encoding mismatch between what's in the file and what the application expects? Have you *set* the encoding somewhere in your application?

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for the reply, This is just a small part of a project. I am not sure whether the locale is set somewhere. If I read the string as a normal string and convert it later to wstring using boost::locale it works. But I am not sure whether it will work every time. While creating std::string from char* (which can have widechar) is it possible to encounter null character before the string end?

Comment: If your input encoding is e.g. UTF-16, you *will* have null characters. You simply cannot assume anything unless you set the encoding explicitly. Ever considered taking a look at [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org)? That's probably the most capable, stable, and portable solution for handling encodings that you will find. Actually it's what boost::locale relies on as backend, just taking out the intermediary -- which is beneficial when you end up on a platform where Boost is distributed *without* ICU support compiled in. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an encoding (or more specifically, decoding) issue. The wide-character API functions will not automatically detect the character encoding of the data. You need to set this in the application, for example:

```
#include <locale.h>

setlocale(LC_ALL, "en.UTF-8");
```

The man page for `fgetws` states:

```
The behavior of fgetws() depends on the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale.
```

so using:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en.UTF-8");
```

should also work.

NOTE: The above assumes the data is UTF-8 encoded.

UPDATE: It is possible to preserve the current locale by doing something like:

```
char *prev_locale = strdup(setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL));
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en.UTF-8");
// ...
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, prev_locale);
free(prev_locale);
```

Comment: Is it possible to setlocale to en.UTF-8 right before the fgetws call and set it back to the previous LC_CTYPE settign right after the use of fgetws. I am not sure what was the setting prior to my fgetws call. Can I ask for the previous setting in any way?