# wprintf doesn't print special character and fgetws returns NULL when one is fund

Tags: c, special-characters

I have an issue with `fgetws` and `wprintf`.

`NULL` is returned when a special character is fund in the File opened before. I don't have this problem with `fgets`.

I tried to use `setlocale`, as recommended here : [fgetws fails to get the exact wide char string from FILE*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936105/fgetws-fails-to-get-the-exact-wide-char-string-from-file)

but it doesn't change nothing.

Moreover, `wprintf(L"éé");` prints `??` (I also don't have this problem with `printf`) in the terminal (on Ubuntu 12), what can be done to avoid this?

Edit : as it is asked in the comments, here is the very simple code :

```
# include "sys.h"
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

int main (void){
  FILE *File = fopen("D.txt", "r");

  wchar_t line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];  
  while (fgetws(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, File))
    wprintf(L"%S", line);

  fclose(File);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer you linked is somewhat wrong; you should never hard-code locale names when calling `setlocale`. For the most part, the second argument to `setlocale` should always be `""`. Without a better explanation of what you're doing it's hard to know what's wrong, but it might help to first redirect output to a file and confirm that the file actually contains 2 bytes `??` and that it's not just your terminal being misconfigured that's printing the `??`.

Comment: I don't understand which other clarifications do you need. Normally just doing `wprintf(L"éé);` should work, no? At the beginning, I asked this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100370/non-ascii-character-declaration/25102707#25102707] because I want to compare special characters and I thought it was better to store it in a wchar_t var rather than a char *.

Comment: Please, provide a complete, compilable and executable, example. Maybe you use `setlocale` wrongly, maybe you also use byte-oriented functions on `stdout` (e.g. `printf`), …

Comment: There are **very many** possible reasons why `wprintf(L"éé");` might not work. `stdout` might already be byte-oriented (in which case `wprintf` invokes UB). Your source file might be in the wrong encoding (i.e. not UTF-8). `setlocale` might have failed or be using a locale with an incorrect encoding. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: The source file is well encoded (UTF-8). So I should use `setlocale` in my code, if yes how?

Comment: Add a call to `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` before using any wide stdio functions. You can use `LC_ALL` if you want, but `LC_CTYPE` is the minimum needed for wide character functions to work as desired.

Comment: Ok, perfect! thanks ;) Don't you want to answer (not in a comment) in order to enable me to accept it and to make it more visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, when a program starts, it is running in the C locale, which is not guaranteed to support any characters except those needed for translating C programs. (It can contain more as an implementation detail, but you cannot rely on this.) In order to use `wchar_t` to store other characters and process them with the wide character conversion functions or wide stdio functions, you need to set a locale in which those characters are supported.

The locales available, and how they are named, vary by system, so you should not attempt to set a locale by name. Instead, pass `""` to `setlocale` to request the "default" locale for the user or the system. On POSIX-like systems, this uses the `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables to determine the preferred locale. As long as the characters you're trying to use exist in the user's locale, your `wprintf` should work.

The call to `setlocale` should look like:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
```

or:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

The former only applies the locale settings to character encoding/character type functions (things that process `wchar_t`). The latter also causes locale to be set for, and affect, a number of other things like message language, formatting of numbers and time, ...

One detail to note is that wide `stdio` functions bind the character encoding of the locale that's in use at the time the stream "becomes wide-oriented", i.e. on the first wide operation that's performed on it. So you need to call `setlocale` before using `wprintf`.